# How do I put the value of vue's item in the check box?

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I want to put item.ai_no in the value of box1 and box2.

```
<tr v-for="item in asReturnList">
    <td>@{{ item.ai_no }}</td>
    <td>@{{ item.cate1 }}</td>
    <td>@{{ item.cate2 }}</td>
    <td>@{{ item.cate3 }}</td>
    <td>@{{ item.ai_cate4 }}</td>
    <td>@{{ item.ai_whyKind }}</td>
    <td>@{{ item.ai_why }}</td>
    <td>@{{ item.ai_pic }}</td>
    <td>@{{ item.ai_qty }}</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="box1" id="" value="@{{ item.ai_no }}"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="box2" id="" value="@{{ item.ai_no }}"></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `v-model`, or you can also use data binding using `:` in front of `value` props. In your case in the checkbox's `value`.

Using `v-model`:

`<input v-model="item.ai_no" type="checkbox">`

Using data binding:

`<input type="checkbox" name="box2" id="" :value="item.ai_no">`

I say, use `v-model` instead.

See this https://jsfiddle.net/greenfoxx/pfb50zms/

Comment: If you use the v-model method as suggested here then changing either of the checkboxes will immediately effect the other checkbox (both checkboxes will map each others state). If you wish to operate the checkboxes independently of each other then you need to go with a defaultvalue approach, defaultvalue="item.ai_no". It all depends on what you want to do with the checkbox after the value is in place.